# netoworkD3: Visualization issues

Tags: r, networkd3

I have created a network graph in R using `networkD3`.

The graph looks so congested.

[image]

So i tried to increase the distance between edges. when I pass in some value through `linkDistance`, the whole shape is distorted and some nodes disappear. I gave some arbitrary value 10 for all the edges.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and add data plus code to reproduce the effect. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example . E.g. this works fine: `library(networkD3);
data(MisLinks); data(MisNodes); forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name", Group = "group", linkDistance = 100)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linkDistance looks like to be a value to multiple the distance between nodes. Maybe you should change this to 2 or 3?

For `linkDistance` you can use `javascript` functions like:

```
value <- 1.3
linkDistance=JS('function(d) {', paste('return d.value *', value,';'), '}'))
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, do you mind taking a look at a related networkD3 question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280218/r-networkd3-package-node-coloring-in-simplenetwork